# open function python not working in __main__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use the `__main__.py` file to run code from. Only the code won't `open()` files in de dir.
I used a `core.py` file that did work with the following code:

```
with open("data/netlist.txt") as f:
    self.list = f.read()
```

In the new main file the error is:

```
with open("data/netlist.txt") as f: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/netlist.txt'
```

The folder looks like this:

[image: The folder looks like this]

Comment: It is exactly what it says, there's no file with the given path. Can you post your directory structure where your main file resides?

Comment: Try to replace `"data/netlist.txt"` with `"data\\netlist.txt"` and make sure there is the `data` folder in your current working directory and it contains `netlist.txt` file.

Comment: @Alperen Do you have some particular reason to believe this is on Windows? I don't see anything in the question to indicate that.

Comment: It's not on windows. The file is in de dir... edit made with a picture of the folder.

Comment: Does `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data/netlist.txt")` work?

Comment: I don't have any particular reason, I just said "try". I guess, @anonymoose's suggesiton is better.

Comment: @Theetje Your `data` folder doesn't contain `netlist.txt` according to the picture. It contains `netlist0.txt`, `netlist1.txt`, ... and `netlist6.txt` but not `netlist.txt`

Comment: No same error. A __init__.py file is not used to import modules in python 3 is it? @Alperen I know It is part of a lagre class. Importing the files and running a lage script. all packed in the old core. I got rid of all the redundant data for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple the path changes when using a __main__.py instead of a core.py.

```
with open("sample/data/netlist.txt") as f:
    self.list = f.read()
```